# Conv1D for classify non-image dataset show error ValueError : `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I found [this paper](https://dergipark.org.tr/en/download/article-file/2050893) they present Convolutional Neural Network can get the best accuracy for non-image classify. So, I want to use CNN with non-image dataset. I download [Early Stage Diabetes Risk Prediction Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ishandutta/early-stage-diabetes-risk-prediction-dataset) form kaggle. I create CNN moldel like this code.

```
dataset = loadtxt('diabetes_data_upload.csv', delimiter=',')
# split into input (X) and output (y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:16]
Y = dataset[:,16]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(16,2, activation='relu', input_shape=(16, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10)
```

It show error like this.

```
ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 15, 1) vs (None,)).
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.keras.layers.Flatten()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten). Something like below can solve youe problem.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


X = np.random.rand(100, 16)
Y = np.random.randint(0,2, size = 100) # <- Because you have two labels, I generate ranom 0,1

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16,2, activation='relu', input_shape=(16, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=10)
```

**Update** by thanks [Ameya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17637655/ameya), we can solve this problem by only using [`tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GlobalAveragePooling1D) too.

(by thanks [Djinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676589/djinn) and [his_comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018062/conv1d-for-classify-non-image-dataset-show-error-valueerror-logits-and-labe/73018155?noredirect=1#comment128971005_73018155), but consider: these are two different approaches that do different things. `Flatten()` preserves all data, and just converts input tensors to a 1D tensor BUT `GlobalAveragePooling1D()` tries to generalize and loses data. Pooling layers with non-image data can significantly affect performance but I've noticed AveragePooling does the least "damage,")

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16,2, activation='relu', input_shape=(16, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

---

```
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6954 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: what about global average pool 1d?

Comment: @Ameya in the paper linked above you read "[...] then pooling and flattening layers were located at the
end of the 1D CNN architecture."

Comment: @Ameya, I checked, only `GlobalAveragePooling1D()` is working (whitout `flatten()`) Do you think we use `GlobalAveragePooling1D()` is better or `Flatten()`?

Comment: yeah, I do global average pool also helps to minimize overfitting by reducing the total number of parameters in the model. that's what I use every time. @I'mahdi this is a great paper please have a look. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4400v3.pdf

Comment: @Ameya, exactly, But don't you think with average pooling and average on feature maybe we lost some features but with `flatten` we only flatten feature and pass to another layers. we use average and maxpooling on very large feature, Do you agree with me or not?

Comment: @Ameya, thanks for sharing your knowledge and those paper ;)

Comment: @I'mahdi yeah, you do lose some details here and there but both max pooling and avg pooling help model to generalize well so as per my knowledge, not a big deal unless and until you are designing another SOTA model (p.s. I'm not a Ph.D. or an expert I'm also learning some stuff.) anyway ciao, have a good one.

Comment: @Ameya, thanks And I agree with you ;)

Comment: As stated in the comments, these are two different approaches that do different things. `Flatten()` preserves all data, just converts input tensors to a 1D tensor. `GlobalAveragePooling1D()` tries to generalize and loses data. It's functionally the same as `AveragePooling1D()` but with max step size. Pooling layers with non-image data can significantly affect performance but I've noticed AveragePooling does the least "damage," so to speak.

Comment: @Djinn, Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge with us, I agree with you and say something like you [comment_here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018062/conv1d-for-classify-non-image-dataset-show-error-valueerror-logits-and-labe/73018155?noredirect=1#comment128964355_73018155)

Comment: @Djinn, I like your summary and use that in the answer, Don't you problem?